# Secure Connection from LAMP to IIS Web API

Tags: c#, api, security, asp.net-web-api, lamp

I already have an existing LAMP application. I am going to integrate a 3rd part API which uses C#, so I'm planning to create a Web API for them to be connected. No other website will connect to the web API other than the LAMP app. How do I make a secure connection from my LAMP app to the web API? Thanks.

Comment: There are different aspects of security: Authentication, Message Integrity, authenticity, privacy ... which one you want?

Comment: Hello, just Authentication

Answer (score 0):

If it is just API calls and nothing dealing with interfaces you can use Encrypted WebSockets or create your Authorization headers... which could be a bit of work and would only work between the those two applications.

The most secure way to lock them up is a combination of a secure HTTP request (HTTPS) coupled with a Client Certificate.

All of these things are quite a tall order; you're best bet is to just get/create a half-way decent SSL certificate and use BASIC authentication.  Your authorization headers will be encrypted.  Even a self-signed certificate would work; make sure to research on how to make a self-signed certificate the most secure it can be.  Also your LAMP server will likely make use of cURL to send the requests to the C# server, you'll want to make use of the `curl -k` option if you're going to be using a self-signed cert.